# Slicer is changing row heights of my pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, slicers

I want to apply a slicer to my pivot table so users can filter easily, but whenever I select something, the row heights change.  I have 'Autofit column widths on update' unchecked and 'Preserve cell formatting on update' is checked'.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You probably already checked this but the only thing that comes to mind at the moment is text wrapping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to figure this out by changing the font size of an empty column outside of my PivotTable to fit the row height I wanted.  For example, I want my row height to be 30, so I changed an empty column's font size to 24.  When I applied my slicer, row heights looked fine!

Comment: Please also accept your answer as the correct answer if this worked for you.

Comment: I just lost 30min debugging... Your suggestion worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just had and resolved the same problem on my workbook. For me, it's related to the formatting in a table header NEXT to the the pivot table being set to Wrap Text.  Unwrapping the header in the adjacent table fixed the problem.

Basically every time I updated the slicer, Excel tried to resize the header in the adjacent table to what it thinks is the proper fit.

Comment: This doesn't provide a new answer to the question. Rather, it is a comment on an existing answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/30429702)

Answer (score 0):

Is the Wrap option perhaps set for cells in the pivottable?

Comment: There's text wrapping on some headers outside of the pivot table, but none inside...

Comment: Just tried removing all the wrap text outside of the pivot table, but still not working

Comment: Pity, would've been a simple solution. Any chance on sharing the file?

Answer (score 0):

The answer marked as correct didn't work for me, but got me on the right track.
Check to see if there are cells anywhere on the same row as the cells that are automatically changing height which are of a larger font size.  In my case, I had hidden cells (columns) to the right of my pivot table which were 8 pts larger than the cells in my pivot.  The pivot table was adjusting the height to accommodate the other cells outside of the pivot table which happened to be hidden from my view so I couldn't see them.